# error: no matching function for call to fix

Tags: c++

```
if(std::get<int>(line) <= 0)
    {
        close(fd);
        pthread_cancel(admin_timeout);
        pthread_exit(0);
    }

error: error: no matching function for call to ‘get(std::tuple<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&)’

if(strcmp(std::get<std::string>(line).c_str(), MANAGER_AUTH_KEY))
    {
        close(fd);
        pthread_cancel(admin_timeout);
        pthread_exit(0);
    }

error: no matching function for call to ‘get(std::tuple<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&)’

memcpy(pass, std::get<std::string>(line).c_str(), std::get<std::string>(line).length());

error: error: no matching function for call to ‘get(std::tuple<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&)’
```

this happens when i compile with g++ -std=c++11 when the code is erased it compiles but when erased doesnt work properly

Answer (score 2):

The version of [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) you're trying to use was added in C++14. In C++11, you have to specify a numeric position like: `std::get<0>(tuple)`.

Comment: can you give an example